# Several bugs with the Preferences > Emails editor

Tags: bug, profile-page

There are several bugs with the *Emails* editor in the [profile > Preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) pane.

1. When you start to type in there, it should enable the button. This doesn't work when you select all text and paste something else in using the mouse. The save button stays disabled.
2. When you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, the save button gets enabled, while <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't. It seems it checks on keyboard activity instead of changing the text.

Can these two related bugs be fixed?

Comment: Problem with `onchange` event of text field is, that it's triggered only when you leave the field. Developers probably wanted "instant" trigger.

Comment: @Sha I meant *on change*, not `onchange` ;)